# Redirect stdout to a truncated file with Node.js

Tags: node.js, process, stdout

I am trying to write a utility script with Node.js, and have to save the stdout of a command to a file. Is there a simple way to do something like `command arg1 arg2 > output.txt` with Node?

I am invoking the command with `spawn()` of the `child_process` module, like `var command = spawn("command", [arg1, arg2])`, but there seems to be no way to redirect the stdout to a file.

Thanks!

Comment: I just googled "nodejs redirect stdout after spawn" and got many promising results.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you'll have to append to a file manually by attaching an event handler to `stdout` as outlined [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process)

It would look something like

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const fs = require('fs')

const cmd = spawn(...)

const appendToLog = data => fs.appendFileSync('my-log.log', `${data}\n`)

cmd.stdout.on('data', appendToLog)
```